# Regular Expression to add double quotes around keys in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I am using jQuery's getJSON function to make a request and handle the JSON response.  The problem is the response I get back is malformed and I can't change it.  The response looks something like this:

```
{
    aNumber: 200,    
    someText: '\'hello\' world',
    anObject: {
        'foo': 'fooValue',
        'bar': '10.0'
    } 
}
```

To be valid JSON, it should look like this:

```
{
    "aNumber": 200,    
    "someText": "'hello' world",
    "anObject": {
        "foo": "fooValue",
        "bar": "10.0"
    } 
}
```

I would like to change the text returned to a valid JSON object. I've used the JavaScript replace function to turn the single quotes into double quotes and the escaped single quotes into single quotes, but now I am stuck on figuring out the best way to add quotes around the key values.

For example, how would I change `foo: "fooValue"` to `"foo":"fooValue"`?  Is there a Regular Expression that can make this easy?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wrote a conversion function in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781226/convert-converted-object-string-to-json-or-object/4781447#4781447), using simple regular expressions, and does not need `eval()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*edit* — came back to point out, first and foremost, that this is not a problem that can be solved with a regular expression.

It's important to distinguish between JSON notation as a serialized form, and JavaScript object constant notation.

This:

```
{ x: "hello" }
```

is a perfectly valid JavaScript value (an expression fragment), so that this:

```
var y = { x: "hello" };
```

gives you exactly the same result as:

```
var y = { "x": "hello" };
```

In other words, the value of "y" in either of those cases will be exactly the same.  Completely, exactly the same, such that it would not be possible to ever tell which of those two constants was used to initialize "y".

Now, if what you want to do is translate a **string** containing JavaScript style "JSON shorthand" without quotes into valid JSON, the only thing to do is parse it and reconstruct the string with quotes around the property names.  That is, you will have to either write your own "relaxed" JSON parser than can cope with unquoted identifiers as property names, or else find an off-the-shelf parser that can handle such relaxed syntax.

In your case, it looks like once you have the "relaxed" parser available, you're done; there shouldn't be any need for you to translate back.  Thankfully, your "invalid" JSON response is completely interpretable by JavaScript itself, so if you trust the data source (and that's a **big** "if") you should be able to evaluate it with "eval()".

Answer (score 19):

This regex will do the trick

```
$json = preg_replace('/([{,])(\s*)([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+?)\s*:/','$1"$3":',$json);
```

It's a php though! I assume it's not a problem converting it to JS.

Comment: Perfect! For my JS friends out there `JSON.parse(dirtyJSON.replace(/([{,])(\s*)([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+?)\s*:/g, '$1"$3":'))`

Answer (score 14):

I was trying to solve the same problem using a regEx in Javascript.  I have an app written for Node.js to parse incoming JSON, but wanted  a "relaxed" version of the parser (see following comments), since it is inconvenient to put quotes around every key (name).  Here is my solution:

```
var objKeysRegex = /({|,)(?:\s*)(?:')?([A-Za-z_$\.][A-Za-z0-9_ \-\.$]*)(?:')?(?:\s*):/g;// look for object names
var newQuotedKeysString = originalString.replace(objKeysRegex, "$1\"$2\":");// all object names should be double quoted
var newObject = JSON.parse(newQuotedKeysString);
```

Here's a breakdown of the regEx:

- `({|,)` looks for the beginning of the object, a `{` for flat objects or `,` for embedded objects.
- `(?:\s*)` finds but does not remember white space
- `(?:')?` finds but does not remember a single quote (to be replaced by a double quote later).  There will be either zero or one of these.
- `([A-Za-z_$\.][A-Za-z0-9_ \-\.$]*)` is the name (or key). Starts with any letter, underscore, $, or dot, followed by zero or more alpha-numeric characters or underscores or dashes or dots or $.
- the last character `:` is what delimits the name of the object from the value.

Now we can use `replace()` with some dressing to get our newly quoted keys:

```
originalString.replace(objKeysRegex, "$1\"$2\":")
```

where the `$1` is either `{` or `,` depending on whether the object was embedded in another object.  `\"` adds a double quote.  `$2` is the name. `\"` another double quote. and finally `:` finishes it off.
Test it out with

```
{keyOne: "value1", $keyTwo: "value 2", key-3:{key4:18.34}}
```

output:

```
{"keyOne": "value1","$keyTwo": "value 2","key-3":{"key4":18.34}}
```

Some comments:

- I have not tested this method for speed, but from what I gather by reading some of these entries is that using a regex is faster than `eval()`
- For my application, I'm limiting the characters that names are allowed to have with `([A-Za-z_$\.][A-Za-z0-9_ \-\.$]*)` for my 'relaxed' version JSON parser.  If you wanted to allow more characters in names (you can do that and still have valid JSON), you could instead use `([^'":]+)` to mean anything other than double or single quotes or a colon.  This would still limit you further than the JSON standard (which allows single quotes in the name) but then you wouldn't be able to parse using this method.  You can have all sorts of stuff in here with this expression `([^'":]+)`, so be careful.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a "good enough" solution for many situations. But please do not fool yourself into thinking that any regular expression will be able to handle all input. For example, consider what happens when this regex is fed this input: `{"sillyValue" : "{hey:there}"}`

Comment: and also it leaves trailing space 
{ name : "value"} => { "name_": "value" }

Comment: Nice solution @John It's helped my specific scenario. Is there any chance you could point me in the direction of applying the same solution to the object's values please?

Answer (score 2):

**UPD 2020:** the object you have is a valid **javascript object**, but not 100% valid [**JSON**](http://www.json.org/js.html).

An easy way to convert it to valid JSON is to utilize the features JavaScript provides you with, [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
JSON.stringify(object)
```

You can run this in your browser's JS console.

To get it formatted (aka "pretty-printed"), you can pass two arguments to this function - the *replacer* (a function which allows you to filter out some of the properties of your object; just pass a `null` if you don't care) and *space* (either the **number** of spaces or a **string** which will be placed before each key-value pair of your object' string representation):

```
JSON.stringify(object, null, 4)
```

In your case, this call

```
JSON.stringify({
    aNumber: 200,    
    someText: '\'hello\' world',
    anObject: {
        'foo': 'fooValue',
        'bar': '10.0'
    } 
}, null, 4)
```

will give you

```
{
    "aNumber": 200,
    "someText": "'hello' world",
    "anObject": {
        "foo": "fooValue",
        "bar": "10.0"
    }
}
```

<del>You **do not** need to do this - you've already got a valid **JSON object**. Read 'bout JSON [here][1].

If you need to get value, you just write `data.whatever` and it just works. E.g.: if you have JSON **object** `data`:

    {
      moo: "foo",
      foo: "bar"
    }

All possible fields are `moo` and `foo` and their use are `data.moo` and `data.foo` respectively. And if you want to use `data` as a jQuery argument, you just pass it as-is: `$.load("http://my.site.com/moo", data, function(response){ /* ... */ })`.

**Note:** in the last example i've mentioned, response will be a string. To make it a valid JSON object use `$.parseJSON(response);` method.</del>

Comment: He's already getting a response string from his server. The problem is that the string is **not** valid JSON.  It's valid JavaScript, however.

Comment: @Pointy, here's some demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kBZu5/ . Please, show me where i'm wrong. Or may be i misunderstood question?

Comment: In true JSON notation, property names - the identifiers on the left side of colons - **must** be quoted. All quoting must be done with double-quote characters ("), not single-quote characters.  See http://json.org for more info. It is a **subset** of JavaScript object literal syntax.

Comment: this is a helpful answer.  While I don't technically have a valid JSON object, I do have valid Javascript.  I would not be able to use jQuery's parseJSON because parseJSON expects well-formed JSON.  But, I would be able to run the response through the eval function to use data.moo or data.foo.

Comment: @Evil E, well, i'm glad it helped you! =)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a malformed "JSON", you will not be able to use jQuery.getJSON.

You can use

```
jQuery.ajax({
      url : myUrl,
      data : myParams,
      type : "GET",
      success : function(jsontext)
      {
          // jsontext is in text format
          jsontext = jsontext.replace("'", "\"");
          // now convert text to JSON object
          var jsonData = eval('(' + jsontext+ ')');

          // rest of the code
      }
 });
```

Comment: Although, using an 'eval' block could be vulnerable and can welcome security issues. You can very well use JSON parser as ---- JSON.parse(jsontext) to get the JSON object instead of eval

Comment: the problem is that the raw text is **not** valid JSON.

Comment: this is a great, working solution and very close to what I implemented after reading the answer from @Pointy.  I used the jQuery.ajax function, but explicitly defined the dataType as 'text'.  There was also no need to replace the quotes.