# Comma Separated Key and Value string to Object using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, string, object

I read a HTML element's property using JavaScript like this:

```
<table data-option="pageSize:10, pageNumber:1, rowNumber:true"></table>
```

I will have a string like this:

```
attrs="pageSize:10, pageNumber:1, rowNumber:true";
```

I have a key and value JavaScript object like this:

```
obj={pageSize:12, pageNumber:1, rowNumber:true}
```

I want to convert my attrs to object like obj.

Comment: Can you amend the HTML at all? If you change the format of the `data-option` value to JSON, jQuery will automatically parse it to an object for you.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Option 1.

Store an entire json-encoded string.

### Option 2.

To convert that from string to an object with `JSON.parse` you'll need double quotes.

Using a regex to add double quotes taken [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29269996/2044039), we get the desired result:

```
attrs = ("{" + attrs + "}").replace(/([{,])(\s*)([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+?)\s*:/g,'$1"$3":');
var obj = JSON.parse(attrs);
```

### UPD:

As mentioned by **epascarello**, if you have unquoted string values there like `name: Jack`, this approach would obviously fail. But if you're putting raw strings there, mind that they might contain commas or spaces or whatever, so you'd better quote them

Comment: Thank you. Option 2 was marvelous.

Comment: Option two works in your case, if the values are unquoted strings, it would fail.

Comment: @epascarello well, yeah, sure it would. But, first of all, unquoting string values seems weird to me (how would one deal with spaces or commas in strings then?), and after all, it's unclear from the statement of the question if those values would be quoted or not so...

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate and create the object yourself

```
var attr = $('table').data('option');
var obj  = {};

$.each(attr.split(','), function(index, item) {
    var parts = $.map(item.split(':'), function(part) {
        part = $.trim(part);
        if ( +part == part ) return +part
        else if ( part === 'true' ) return true
        else if ( part === 'false') return false
        else return part;
    });
    obj[parts[0]] = parts[1];
});
```

```js
var attr = $('table').data('option');
var obj  = {};

$.each(attr.split(','), function(index, item) {
 var parts = $.map(item.split(':'), function(part) {
     part = $.trim(part);
     if ( +part == part ) return +part
        else if ( part === 'true' ) return true
        else if ( part === 'false') return false
        else return part;
 });
    obj[parts[0]] = parts[1];
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table data-option="pageSize:10, pageNumber:1, rowNumber:true"></table>
```