# Insert array from csv using pymongo

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pandas, numpy

I have a csv file with array in string format as below:

```
date,name,criteria
2018-05-16,John,"[{'age':35},{'birthyear':1983}]"
2018-05-16,Jane,"[{'age':36},{'birthyear':1982}]"
```

I am using Python with pandas and numpy for processing this

I need to import this file into MongoDB collection in following format :

```
{
   "date":'2018-05-16',
   "name":"John",
   "criteria" : [
         {"age":35},
         {"birthyear" : 1983}
   ]
},
{
   "date":'2018-05-16',
   "name":"Jane",
   "criteria" : [
         {"age":36},
         {"birthyear" : 1982}
   ]
 }
```

`

I tried using json formatter , but after insertion into Mongodb I get the array to be same as in csv file.

I have tried following approaches:

```
#Approach 1
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
records = json.loads(df.T.to_json()).values()
db.tmp_collection.insert_many(data.to_dict('record'))



#Approach 2
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
data_json = json.loads(df.to_json(orient='records'))
db.tmp_collection.insert_many(data_json)
```

Both give following output in Mongodb collection :

```
{
"date" : "2018-05-16",
"name" : "John",
"criteria" : "[{age:35},{birthyear:1983}]"
}
```

Can you suggest some better way. 
P.S. i am new to Python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the csv, the "criteria" values are not valid json because the strings (age, birthyear) aren't quoted. Is it possible for you to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

As noted the main issue is the JSON "like" data within the "string" for the `criteria` lacks quotes around the keys. With quotes properly in place you can parse the string into a list the data is structured how you want.

You could actually run [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) over the existing list and replace the `criteria` with the parsed version.

Given the source data in the form you stated:

```
date,name,criteria
2018-05-16,John,"[{age:35},{birthyear:1983}]"
2018-05-16,Jane,"[{age:36},{birthyear:1982}]"
```

Then the important parts are:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
records = json.loads(df.to_json(orient='records'))

pattern = r"({|,)(?:\s*)(?:')?([A-Za-z_$\.][A-Za-z0-9_ \-\.$]*)(?:')?(?:\s*):"

records = map(lambda x:
  dict(x.items() +
    {
      'criteria': json.loads(
        re.sub(pattern, "\\1\"\\2\":", x['criteria'])
      )
    }.items()
  ),
  records
)
```

Which is basically going through each item in the list which came out earlier and doing a substitution on the "string" to quote the keys in the objects. Then of course parses the now valid JSON string into a list of dictionary objects.

That would make data like:

```
[{u'criteria': [{u'age': 35}, {u'birthyear': 1983}],
  u'date': u'2018-05-16',
  u'name': u'John'},
 {u'criteria': [{u'age': 36}, {u'birthyear': 1982}],
  u'date': u'2018-05-16',
  u'name': u'Jane'}]
```

Which you can then pass to the [`insert_many()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many) to create the documents in the collection keeping that format that you want.

```
db.tmp_collection.insert_many(records)
```

Attribution to [regular expression to add double quotes around keys in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25146786/2313887) for the regular expression pattern used here.

Personally I would take that a little further and at least parse to `datetime`:

```
records = map(lambda x:
  dict(x.items() +
    {
      'date': datetime.strptime(x['date'], '%Y-%m-%d'),
      'criteria': json.loads(
        re.sub(pattern, "\\1\"\\2\":", x['criteria'])
      )
    }.items()
  ),
  records
)
```

MongoDB will use a BSON Date when inserted into the collection, and that's a lot more useful than a string.

And again, "personally" I would not be using "named keys" inside a list for MongoDB. Instead I would rather "remap" to something more standard like `"k"` and `"v"` as in:

```
records = map(lambda x:
  dict(x.items() +
    {
      'date': datetime.strptime(x['date'], '%Y-%m-%d'),
      'criteria':
      [i for s in map(lambda y: [{ 'k': k, 'v': v } for k,v, in y.iteritems()] , json.loads(
        re.sub(pattern, "\\1\"\\2\":", x['criteria'])
      )) for i in s]
    }.items()
  ),
  records
)
```

Which gives a structure like:

```
[{u'criteria': [{'k': u'age', 'v': 35}, {'k': u'birthyear', 'v': 1983}],
  u'date': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 16, 0, 0),
  u'name': u'John'},
 {u'criteria': [{'k': u'age', 'v': 36}, {'k': u'birthyear', 'v': 1982}],
  u'date': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 16, 0, 0),
  u'name': u'Jane'}]
```

With the main reason being that "querying" with MongoDB is going to be a lot more useful if the path is more consistent like that.

Comment: getting Error `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 24 (char 23)`    for inserting into collection.    Tried using json.dumps in place of json.loads but that gives `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_items' and 'dict_items'` error

Comment: @cartman619 Not from the items you included in the question. Works fine for me, otherwise I would not have posted it here. I don't have any code that says `dict_items`. Run on something different to what you actually asked at your own peril.

Comment: @cartman619 Did you change your CSV data source? You changed it in the question. If you did actually add the quotes within the CSV itself then you don't need the `re.sub` line in here, and can merely pass the `x['criteria']` to the `json.loads()`. The whole point of that substitution was that your original posted data does not have those quotes on the keys to make it valid JSON for parsing.

Comment: yes i have changed to csv to reflect the correctness, sorry for that. I commented the   `re.sub`   part and still get the   `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 24 (char 23)`   error when inserting in collection.  Also is there any way i can print    `records`   after the   `json.loads()`   , so that i can check why this error

Comment: @cartman619 What do you mean by "when inserting the collection"? `records` is simply a list of dicts and that is all you need to pass in to `.insert_many()` without doing anything else. That's exactly what I am showing you but you seem to be implying you are trying to run `loads()` on that content. You don't do that as the pymongo method expects "python data" and not JSON. And of course you can print it. I'm showing the `pprint` output within the answer, so that's how I'm doing it.